# Problem in FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to make a simple todo list android app using kotlin and firebase realtime database.. Here is mainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    // reference for FAB
    val fab = findViewById<View>(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton

    //Adding click listener for FAB
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->

        //Show Dialog here to add new Item
        addNewItemDialog()

    }

    lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

}

class ToDoItem {

    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): ToDoItem = ToDoItem()
    }

    var objectId: String? = null
    var itemText: String? = null
    var done: Boolean? = false
}

object Constants {
    @JvmStatic val FIREBASE_ITEM: String = "todo_item"
}

private fun addNewItemDialog(){

    val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    val itemEditText = EditText(this)
    alert.setMessage("Add New Item")
    alert.setTitle("Enter To Do Item Text")

    alert.setView(itemEditText)

    alert.setPositiveButton("Submit"){ dialog, positiveButton ->

        val todoItem = ToDoItem.create()
        todoItem.itemText = itemEditText.text.toString()
        todoItem.done = false

        //we first make a push so that a new item is made with a unique id

        val newItem = mDatabase.child(Constants.FIREBASE_ITEM).push()
        todoItem.objectId = newItem.key

        //then, we used the reference to set the value on that ID
        newItem.setValue(todoItem)

        dialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item saved with ID" + todoItem.objectId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    alert.show()
}
```

give me an error unresolved reference: DatabaseReference and unresolved reference: FloatingActionButton

Here is the code for xml(ListView and FloatingActionButton)

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/items_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
```

here is gradle dependencies(both)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```

}

Where did I go wrong??? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: post your imports and gradle dependencies

Comment: @Domin I just edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use Firebase realtime database, you need to add to your `build.gradle` file, the corresponding dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```

Google services is also needed to be added as the last line in your file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In this case, the following message:

```
unresolved reference: DatabaseReference
```

Will disappear. Now to be able to use this line of code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

Two imports are needed:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
```

Regarding the second one:

```
unresolved reference: FloatingActionButton
```

This is the Design Support Floating Action Button supplied by Google that should be added:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

It also means that you need to add an import, which is:

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

Comment: thanks error gone regarding firebasedatabase and database reference but still error in this line val newItem = mDatabase.child(Constants.FIREBASE_ITEM).push() unresolved reference mDatabase and also show me red line in both these lines
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

Comment: Problem solved just put mDatabase inside addNewItemDialog() function.. and it worked.. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You are missing core dependencies and need to add SDK in Build.gradle.
Check out Google Documentation with instructions:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
and hence it seems you are willing to use realtime database add also this dependency:
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'`

Comment: Thanks two issues are cleared but in this line "val newItem = mDatabase.child(Constants.FIREBASE_ITEM).push()" give error unresolved reference mDatabase and also when I hover it says mDatabase is assigned but never accessed. any idea how to rectify this??

Answer (score 0):

In your Project 
Goto **Tools-->Firebase**
It will open an Assistant 
Then Perform Following Steps :

**1. Select RealTime Database

 2. Click on Save and Retrieve data

 3. Connect Your App to Firebase

 4. Add the RealtimeDatabase to Your App**